# Configurar Startup.cs no Asp.Net Core

Tags: asp.net-core, .net-core, asp.net-core-web-api

Olá, não estou conseguindo configurar a minha Startup.cs para executar meu aplicativo em .Net Core.
O seguinte erro está sendo executado:

An error occurred while starting the application.
InvalidOperationException: No service for type 'Owin.IAppBuilder' has been registered.
Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceProviderServiceExtensions.GetRequiredService(IServiceProvider provider, Type serviceType)

Exception: Could not resolve a service of type 'Owin.IAppBuilder' for the parameter 'app' of method 'Configure' on type 'PROJETO.WebAPI.Startup'.
Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting.Internal.ConfigureBuilder.Invoke(object instance, IApplicationBuilder builder)

InvalidOperationException: No service for type 'Owin.IAppBuilder' has been registered.

Abaixo o código da minha classe Startup.cs, agradeço qualquer ajuda!

```
[assembly: OwinStartup("BANCO_DADOS", typeof(Startup))]
namespace PROJETO_APP.WebAPI
{
public class Startup
{
    //public Startup(IConfiguration configuration)
    //{
    //    Configuration = configuration;
    //}



    //public IConfiguration Configuration { get; }

    public void Configure(IAppBuilder app)
    {
        var config = new HttpConfiguration();
        var container = new UnityContainer();

        ConfigureDependencyInjection(config, container);

        ConfigureWebApi(config);

        // configuracao de autencticacao
        ConfigureOAuth(app, container.Resolve<IProfissionalApplication>(), container.Resolve<ISistemaContextoApplication>());

        app.UseStageMarker(PipelineStage.MapHandler);

        app.UseCors(CorsOptions.AllowAll);

        app.UseWebApi(config);
    }

    public void ConfigureWebApi(HttpConfiguration config)
    {
        // configuracoes pertinentes aos JSONs
        var formatters = config.Formatters;
        formatters.Remove(formatters.XmlFormatter);

        var jsonSettings = formatters.JsonFormatter.SerializerSettings;
        jsonSettings.Formatting = Formatting.Indented;

        jsonSettings.ContractResolver = new CamelCasePropertyNamesContractResolver();
        formatters.JsonFormatter.SerializerSettings.DateFormatHandling = DateFormatHandling.IsoDateFormat;
        formatters.JsonFormatter.SerializerSettings.DateTimeZoneHandling = DateTimeZoneHandling.Unspecified;
        formatters.JsonFormatter.SerializerSettings.PreserveReferencesHandling = PreserveReferencesHandling.None;
        formatters.JsonFormatter.SerializerSettings.ReferenceLoopHandling = ReferenceLoopHandling.Ignore;

        config.MapHttpAttributeRoutes();

        config.Routes.MapHttpRoute("DefaultApi", "api/{controller}/{action}/{id}",
            new { id = RouteParameter.Optional });
    }

    // This method gets called by the runtime. Use this method to add services to the container.
    public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
    {


        services.AddMvc().SetCompatibilityVersion(CompatibilityVersion.Version_2_1);
        services.AddCors();
        services.AddSingleton<IUnitOfWork, UnitOfWork>();


        #region Injeção de dependências de applications

        services.AddSingleton<IAreaApplication, AreaApplication>();
        services.AddSingleton<IAtividadeApplication, AtividadeApplication>();

        #endregion

        #region Injeção de dependências de repositories

        services.AddSingleton<IAreaRepository, AreaRepository>();
        services.AddSingleton<IAtividadeRepository, AtividadeRepository>();
        #endregion

        services.AddDbContext<BANCO_DADOSWebAPIContext>(options =>
                options.UseSqlServer(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["Banco_Dados"].ToString()));
    }

    public void ConfigureDependencyInjection(HttpConfiguration config, UnityContainer container)
    {
        container.RegisterType<IContextService, ContextService>(new HierarchicalLifetimeManager());

    }

    public void ConfigureOAuth(IAppBuilder app, IProfissionalApplication usuarioApplication, ISistemaContextoApplication sistemaContextoApplication)
    {
        var oAuthServerOptions = new OAuthAuthorizationServerOptions
        {
            AllowInsecureHttp = true,
            TokenEndpointPath = new PathString("/api/security/token"),
            AccessTokenExpireTimeSpan = TimeSpan.FromDays(2),
            Provider = new SimpleAuthorizationServerProvider(usuarioApplication, sistemaContextoApplication)
        };

        // Token Generation
        app.UseOAuthAuthorizationServer(oAuthServerOptions);
        app.UseOAuthBearerAuthentication(new OAuthBearerAuthenticationOptions());
    }


}
```

}

Comment: Olá, é uma aplicação nova ou legado? Tem necessidade de utilizar o OWIN no ASP.NET Core? Já que ele foi reconstruído usando as especificações do OWIN e com modificações/melhorias.

Comment: Oi Rafael, obrigado a atenção.Mas é uma aplicação legado, mas tinha somente a startup.cs configurada e uma outra classe com uma interface .

Comment: Olá, tente adicionar o app.UseOwin(), talvez seja isso que falta para injetar o serviço solicitado.

Comment: Não deu, nem a opção de importar a biblioteca caso tivesse essa opção, mas nas minhas dependências do projeto eu tenho o Microsoft.Owin.

Comment: Olá, @J.Moura. Tente alterar a posição do método "ConfigureServices". Deixe-o como primeiro método. Como neste [exemplo da Microsoft](https://docs.microsoft.com/pt-br/aspnet/core/fundamentals/startup?view=aspnetcore-3.1).